# What's wrong with this expression?

Tags: ruby

Here is my expression

```
Math.sqrt((4.5-4.0 ** 2) + (1.0 - 2.0 ** 2))
```

and I get this

```
Math::DomainError: Numerical argument is out of domain - "sort"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: have you added `require 'cmath'` ?

Comment: You can't pass a negative number and `(4.5-4.0 ** 2) + (1.0 - 2.0 ** 2) #=> -14.5` is negative.

Answer (score 3):

Because multiplication it's evaluated before addition, the result of the expression in parentheses is negative, and ruby won't take the square root of a negative number.

Comment: Maybe I'm a little pedantic, but `**` is the exponentiation operator, not multiplication. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you probably meant to write:

```
Math.sqrt( (4.5-4.0)**2 + (1.0 - 2.0)**2 )
```

As written earlier, you were trying to take the square root of a negative number,
which won't work in any standard programming language.